# How do I avoid tracking certain files completely?

Tags: git

I'm sort of a novice/intermediate with Git, but I'm having trouble understanding something about the staging index.  I'm an iOS developer and every time I work on an XCode project and then run git status in my project folder, I frequently see that files like `info.plist` or `.DS_Store` are not staged for commits.

I don't care about files like these and don't want to commit them.  How can I tell git to completely ignore these files and not prompt me to stage them?

I tried setting up a `.gitignore_global` in my home directory that contains the following:

```
# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

# Packages #
############
# it's better to unpack these files and commit the raw source
# git has its own built in compression methods
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

# Logs and databases #
######################
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db

# XCode Related files #
######################
*.plist
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  I've seen posts on SO about using git rm --cached  to untrack files, but then it shows up as a file that is to be "deleted".  I don't want to commit that change and alarm anyone.

What is the correct solution to tell git to permanently ignore files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+forget+tracked+files

Answer (score 2):

Global `.gitignore` file should be configured with `core.excludesfile` global option, otherwise Git won't apply it:

```
$ git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

Comment: Hi Karol, yes I had done that from the start.  That's how I created the .gitignore_global file.  I just don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: @JFortYork can you confirm this with `git config --global --list` and then try `git add -A` to see if `.DS_Store` gets added? Your current setup should work.

Comment: I see this line (among others): core.excludesfile=/Users/ja6101409/.gitignore_global.  After doing the git add command, do you want me to check .gitignore_global?

Comment: @JFortYork what is your git version?

Comment: Judging from the presence of `.DS_Store` in the list of files to be ignored, the OP is on a Mac.  On macOS 10.14.6 Mojave with XCode 10.3 (that's the latest GA version of macOS as of 2019-08-01), the version of Git is 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117).  I've not kept a record of previous versions of Git.

Comment: My git version is 2.17.2.

Answer (score 0):

As [Karol Dowbecki said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57312677/1256452), you probably want something like:

```
$ git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

but that doesn't fix existing problems.

#### The problem

A *commit* is a Git object that stores files (as a snapshot) plus some metadata.  Each commit has a unique hash ID: every Git in the world that has that commit, has it by *that* hash ID; no other commit can ever have that same hash ID.  Note, too, that commits are frozen forever.  Nothing—no power in the universe—can change an existing commit.<sup>1</sup>

Now, suppose that you have gotten some file you *want* to be ignored, into some existing commit.  Never mind *how* it got in there, just consider that it *is* in there.  If you `git checkout` that commit, Git will copy that file into your index and work-tree.

Your index is largely invisible, but it holds a copy of *every file* in the commit you just checked out.  Git takes the files from the deep-freeze version stored via the commit, copies it—or technically, its blob hash—to your index, and then copies the file to your work-tree so that you can see and work on it.  The index is also where you build the *next* commit you will make.

When you run `git add`, you tell your Git: *take the version of the file that's in my work-tree now, and copy it into the index.*  This overwrites the previous copy—which *was* there, even though `git status` didn't say anything—with a new, different copy.  If you run `git commit` now, the new commit has the updated file.  It also has all the un-updated files that you *didn't* overwrite.  That is how and why every commit is a full snapshot of *all* of your files: the `git commit` command actually makes commits from the *index*.  The index holds all the files, always.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can *stop using* a commit, and make your Git forget that it ever existed.  It still does exist, of course, unless and until every Git repo that *has* the commit, drops it.  After that, the hash ID—the true name of that commit—will just elicit a: *say what? I don't know a commit by that hash ID* response from every Git in the world.  To drop a commit, you must drop all of its descendants as well, because the hash ID of a commit is built in part from the hash IDs of every ancestor commit.  See the Wikipedia article on [Merkle trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) for more.

Also, two different commits *could* share the same hash ID, *provided* that those two Gits never meet each other.  (I like to think of these as doppelgänger commits.)  If the two Gits do meet, they'll refuse to share the doppelgänger commit, *and* any other commit that has the doppelgänger commit as part of its history cannot go into the other Git either.

---

#### What does all this have to do with `.gitignore` and tracked files?

A *tracked file* is a file that's in the index.

That's it.  That's all there is to it.  A file is tracked if and only if it's in the index *right now*.  A file that is in the work-tree, but not in the index, is *untracked*.

So, suppose `.DS_Store` is in your work-tree right now (because Finder has written or created it).  Is `.DS_Store` in your index right now?  If so, it's tracked.  If not, it's untracked.

Listing a file in `.gitignore` tells Git that **if** the file is untracked, Git should:

- *not complain* about this, and
- *not auto-add* the file when you use an en-masse `git add` of many files (`*` or `.` or whatever).

In fact, if the `.DS_Store` file is untracked and you have it listed in a `.gitignore`, and you run `git add .DS_Store` explicitly, even *that* won't *add* it: it will tell you that the file is ignored and you should use `--force` if you really want it added.

But ... what if `.DS_Store` is already in the index?  *In this case, listing it in a `.gitignore` has no effect.*  It's already tracked.  It's too late!  You can `git rm` it, with or without `--cached`, to *remove* it from your index *right now*.  Then it's untracked.  It won't be in the *next* commit.

That doesn't remove it from any existing commits that have it.  *Nothing* can do that.  Those commits, found by their hash IDs, will have `.DS_Store` in them forever.

#### What you can do about this

You can make new and improved (but different, and different-hash-ID) commits that are *like* the old ones but *don't have* the file.  Because commits encode their ancestor hash IDs, you have to do this for pretty much *every* commit in your repository.  Then you can get yourself and everyone else in the world that uses this Git repository or a clone of it, to switch from the old commits to the new-and-improved ones.  That's fairly painful, though it's a one-time pain for each user of this Git repository or clone-thereof.  The `git filter-branch` command can do this, or there are tools like The BFG that are faster and more user-friendly, i.e., less painful, that can do it.

Your other option is to leave these problematic commits alone.  They're still there, in your history, but you can `git checkout` each branch tip commit, *fix it up* so that the unwanted files *aren't* in the index *right now*, and then `git commit` to make a *new* commit that becomes the new tip commit of that branch.  Now each branch's tip commit *doesn't* have the unwanted files, and `git checkout` of that branch *won't* try to create the file.

The problem this leaves behind is that if you ever *use* one of these historic commits—perhaps as part of `git merge`, or perhaps via `git checkout`—they'll have the unwanted files.  How messy is that?

- Well, for `git merge`, maybe not messy at all: if all your branch tips *don't* have the file, and you `git merge` some other branch-tip with this branch-tip, and the merge base *does* have the file, your Git will say: *Ah, you and they both deleted `.DS_Store`, so that's all good, we'll keep `.DS_Store` deleted in the new merge commit.*
- But for `git checkout`: kind of messy.  If you `git checkout` one of thes old commits, Git will want to put, say, `.DS_Store` into your index and work-tree.  In some cases—e.g., there's no `.DS_Store` file in your work-tree right now because you removed it and Finder hasn't gotten around to creating it again—Git will be able to create the file.  In others, you can use `git checkout -f` to forcibly overwrite the file.  (How this affects whatever uses the file, depends on the file and the whatever.  For Finder and `.DS_Store`, at least, it's not too terrible.)

  But note that as soon as you switch *away* from this commit—with `git checkout master` for instance—your Git will compare what's in the index to what's in the commit you're moving to.  That other commit *doesn't* have a `.DS_Store`.  So your Git now *removes* `.DS_Store` from the index *and from the work-tree*.

  This removal is allowed if the `.DS_Store` in the work-tree matches the one in the index, or if you use `git checkout -f`.  But it's *also* allowed if `.DS_Store` is marked *ignored*.  For `.DS_Store`, that's not that big a deal: Finder will just create a new one.  For other files, and other programs, it might be a big deal.  Some files are pretty important.  You ought to be able to mark them as *ignored but precious:* don't save with *new* commits, but don't remove from work-tree either.  But you can't, at least not with today's Git.

It's up to you whether to do anything.  If you replace all your old bad commits, it's painful but the result is good.  If you do nothing, you need to be a little bit careful.  Since most ignore rules are mostly in *committed* `.gitignore` files, the lack of ability to mark ignored files as "precious" doesn't bite very often.  However, using *global* ignore rules, it *does* bite.  Cave <s>canem</s> stultus!<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>Using the translation of *Git* as *idiot, stupid person* and then google translate.  It's Git itself being insulted here, not the user.